# How to transpose all rows into columns with particular column as header in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I want to transpose each row of the table into different columns making one particular row as a header for the transposed table. Please help me out with this asap. Any simple example would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`:

```
select 
    --userID, Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4
    *
from (
    select '1' as UserID,'1' as Stage,'1-1-2013' as [Date] union all
    select '1','2','2-1-2013' union all
    select '2','1','1-1-2013' union all
    select '1','3','5-1-2013' union all
    select '2','2','3-1-2013' union all
    select '3','1','6-1-2013' union all
    select '3','2','8-1-2013' union all
    select '1','4','10-1-2013' union all
    select '3','3','12-1-2013'
) x
pivot (
    max([Date]) for Stage in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) p
```

More about this topic:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/